# HttpWebRequest "depecrated"

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, .net, asp.net-core

Hola comunidad estoy implementando un proyecto y utilizo la clase abstracta HttpWebRequest la cual Microsoft ya la puso como deprecated a continuacion el codigo que tengo.

```
public async Task<Usuario> Crear(Usuario entidad, Stream foto = null, string nombreFoto = "", string urlPlantillaCorreo = "")
{
  Usuario usuarioExiste = await _repositorio.Obtener(u => u.Correo == entidad.Correo);

  if(usuarioExiste != null)
    throw new TaskCanceledException("El correo ya existe");

  try
  {
    string claveGenerada = _utilidadesService.GenerarClave();
    entidad.Clave = _utilidadesService.ConvertirSha256(claveGenerada);
    entidad.NombreFoto = nombreFoto;

    if (foto != null)
    {
      string urlFoto = await _fireBaseService.SubirStorage(foto, "carpeta_usuario", nombreFoto);
      entidad.UrlFoto = urlFoto;
    }

    Usuario usuarioCreado = await _repositorio.Crear(entidad);

    if(usuarioCreado.IdUsuario == 0)
      throw new TaskCanceledException("No se pudo crear el usuario");

    if(urlPlantillaCorreo != "")
    {
      urlPlantillaCorreo = urlPlantillaCorreo.Replace("[correo]", usuarioCreado.Correo).Replace("[clave]", claveGenerada);
      string htmlCorreo = "";

      HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(urlPlantillaCorreo);
      HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
  
    }
```

Como podria cambiar los ultimos metodos para usar HttpClient como me recomienda Microsoft? Muchas gracias

Comment: Estas pidiciendo que codifiquen por ti ese metodo y no todos estaran dispuestos a hacerlo. Intenta mejor investigar sobre como utilizar `HttpClient`, implemetar la solucion y si tienes una pregunta en especifica con tu implementacion entonces te pudiera ayudar. Aqui [una pagina que con ejemplo explica](https://zetcode.com/csharp/httpclient/) de manera sencilla como hacerlo. Suerte.

Comment: Dale una mirada a [Realización de solicitudes HTTP mediante IHttpClientFactory en ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-requests?view=aspnetcore-7.0). Que utilza [HttpClientFactory](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/core/extensions/httpclient-factory?source=recommendations) para ayudarnos a crear instancias de HtpClient. Puedes con esta documentacion refactorizar tu codigo y extiende tu pregunta con el ejemplo que armas para ayudarte mas puntualmente.